# remove all items from hastable collecton

Tags: asp.net, hashtable

I am trying to delete all the items in my Hashtable with this code

```
Monitor.Enter(myhasatable);
 foreach (object key in myhasatable.Keys)
            {

                    myhasatable.Remove(key.ToString());

            }
 Monitor.Exit(myhasatable);
```

I am getting error :

> system.invalidoperationexception collection was modified enumeration
>   operation may not execute

and them my server get stuck until I refresh it

Any idea what can cause this problem?

Thnaks

Comment: Why are you setting monitors?

Comment: @asawyer: Presumably because another thread could potentially be reading the hashtable at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while you iterate over it. Try calling [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.clear.aspx) instead.

Also, try to avoid using `Hashtable` in new code. Prefer to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` if you have a choice.

Your server deadlocks because the `Monitor.Exit` is not reached when an exception is thrown on the line before. You could fix this by putting that code in a finally block. But instead of using a `Monitor`, I suggest you use `lock` as this automatically releases the lock for you even in the presence of exceptions.

With all these changes, your code becomes much simpler:

```
lock (dict)
{
    dict.Clear();
}
```

Comment: what happen if I want to remove only one item?can I use the code above with specific key?

Comment: @baaroz: You can use: `lock(dict) { dict.Remove(key); }`

Comment: As an alternative to manual lockings, take a look at `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Did you try consulting the documentation?

```
myHashTable.Clear()
```

[HashTable Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[HashTable.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.clear%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

How about just doing:

```
myhasatable.Clear():
```